# Using Hist function to build series of 1D histograms in Python 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using pythons hist function to generate 1d histograms each linked to a given experiment. 
Now I understand that the Hist function allows one to plot multiple histograms on the same x axis for comparison. I normally use something akin to the following for this purpose and the result is a very nice plot where x1,x2 and x3 are defined as follows 
x1 = lengths expt1
x2 = lengths expt2
x3 = lengths expt3

```
P.figure()
n, bins, patches = P.hist( [x0,x1,x2], 10, weights=[w0, w1, w2], histtype='bar')
P.show()
```

I was hoping to try achieve a 3d effect however and therefore I ask dose anyone know if it is it possible to have each unique histogram offset from the other in the y plane by a given unit thus generating a 3d effect.

I would appreciate any help on this .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you just want `matplotlib.pyplot.bar3d`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x0, x1, x2 = [np.random.normal(loc=loc, size=100) for loc in [1, 2, 3]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

yspacing = 1
for i, measurement in enumerate([x0, x1, x2]):
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(measurement, bins=10)
    dx = np.diff(bin_edges)
    dy = np.ones_like(hist)
    y = i * (1 + yspacing) * np.ones_like(hist)
    z = np.zeros_like(hist)
    ax.bar3d(bin_edges[:-1], y, z, dx, dy, hist, color='b', 
            zsort='average', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]